# How to tell command-t to ignore a specific directory

Tags: command, working-directory

I have a very large number of files under a specific directory.
If I start `vim` from the wrong place, `command-t` tries to index the whole thing, which results in vim hanging for a long time before `command-t` gives up saying that there are too many files.

I don't want the content of that directory to be indexed by `command-t`, so following `:help command-t-wildignore` I tried setting `wildignore` with `:set wildignore=/absolute/path/to/nasty/folder/*`.
Issuing `set wildignore` before trying `command-t` confirms that `wildignore` is correctly set up.
However, `command-t` keeps on *not* ignoring said folder.

I also tried with `:set wildignore=relative/path/to/folder/*` but to no avail (and I would prefer to ignore a specific folder with its absolute path anyway).
I didn't find the explanation of how to use `wildignore` particularly clear though, so I may be using the wrong syntax.

What syntax should be used for this to work properly?

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation](https://github.com/wincent/command-t/blob/master/doc/command-t.txt#L1102-L1140)?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I mean... isn't that exactly what I mentioned in the second paragraph?

Comment: or true, then you should probably raise an issue with the plugin author?

Comment: I too am having problems with `wildignore` (but not for Command-T, just for vanilla Vim). I came across [this blog post](https://langram.org/2016/12/27/excluding-with-vims-wildignore/) which suggests that sometimes it can be difficult to get `wildignore` to work how you want it to.

Answer (score 2):

What's missing is the leading `*` in the wildignore value.

[command-t's help docs](https://github.com/wincent/command-t/blob/master/doc/command-t.txt#L1136) have an initially inscrutable, but actually helpful matrix of 'pattern'->'match' patterns, but the sort of buried lede is that
`foo/` and `foo/*` both "miss" all matches you might expect them to if you're coming from other glob matchers (they actually match *nothing* for the purposes of command-t). The docs don't really specify the behavior using absolute paths, but * think the missing leading `*` is what's hurting here. This would probably be the correct setting (assuming you have no other `wildignore`s set)

```
:set wildignore=*/relative/path/to/folder
```

Here's what I have to ignore node modules and rust build assets in my projects (I use `+=` so I can rearrange them easily)

```
:set wildignore+=*/node_modules
:set wildignore+=*/target/debug,*/target/CACHEDIR.TAG
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!